# Initialize a static pointer to parent in class object in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I'd like to be able to access all of the nodes in my Mesh class from the Element class. I believe I have both classes correctly setup to do this, but I'm not clear on the best practice to initialize the static pointer to Mesh inside of Element. What do you normally do for this?

Thanks!

The code (so far)

//Mesh.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MESH_H
#define MESH_H

#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include "Eigen/Eigen"
#include "Element.h"
#include "Node.h"

class Mesh {
public:
    std::vector< Node* >                m_Nodes;
    std::vector< Element* >             m_Elements;

    Eigen::MatrixXd                     m_K;
    Eigen::VectorXd                     m_F;
    Eigen::VectorXd                     m_u;

    void Mesh::LoadFile(wchar_t* MeshFile);


};

#endif
```

//Element.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef ELEMENT_H
#define ELEMENT_H

#include <vector>

class Mesh;

class Element {
public:
    static Mesh *                       m_Parent;
    static int                          m_ElementCount;
    int                                 m_ElementIndex;
    std::vector< int >                  m_ElementNodes;
};

#endif
```

Comment: This doesn't sound right.  Why would you want the Element **class** to be able to access all of the Mesh **objects**?

Comment: not mesh objects - I'm only going to be dealing with a single mesh at a time. The mesh contains a list of nodes which the element will use to determine stiffness. In my current code iteration I pass the list of nodes be reference into the element at construction and calculate from there. I'd really rather be able to m_Parent.m_Nodes(Node1).Coordinates

Comment: Ah, sorry I misread.  Even so, it still doesn't sound like a good idea; inevitably you'll find that you need more than one mesh, and then your entire design would be broken.  A much better design is to pass the relevant Mesh object to the static methods that need it.

Comment: I don't know how realistic multiple meshes is for this kind of application. I guess if this was a commercial rendering software it would make sense; but, as this is a simple building analysis program it doesn't make much sense to have multiple meshes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the static pointer (in any source file; not in `*.h`):

```
Mesh* Element::m_Parent; // initialized to NULL by the system
```

In addition, to initialize it, use the following syntax :

```
Element::m_Parent = whatever;
```

I tried not to change anything in your class design, but you should think about which member functions and fields should be `static` and which should not; the design doesn't look convenient now.

Comment: got it. Thank you. Didn't realize that the variable needed to be declared in the *.cpp file as well.

Answer (score 1):

I lack reputation to comment on your post, so I have to post here.

Why not just have each Element instance have its own pointer to its parent?  Each pointer can point to the same Mesh object.  Is the memory savings really that important?

Even if you do end up with a singleton mesh, if, in the future, you do want to extend to multiple meshes, each with a group of elements, the change will be easier to do.

If you *do* need to have a static pointer to the parent mesh, you could encapsulate construction of the elements in a method of Mesh, and set the parent pointer to *this* in Mesh's constructor.

Comment: I've tried this but it feeds me unresolved external symbol error



error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class Mesh * Element::m_Parent"

Comment: Memory isn't critical at this point, my meshes have 8 elements at most right now. But in the not so distant future my meshes will have 10,000 elements at the bottom end; I'm not certain whether this is too big a burden or not on the system.